# XML schema - namespace choice ambiguity

Tags: xml, xsd, namespaces

I have the following choice sequence as part of an XML schema. Ideally, I want a sequence where either:

1. Elements from `my:namespace` must be strictly parsed.
2. Elements from any other namespace, excluding `##targetNamespace` and `my:namespace`, should be skipped during parsing/validation.

```
<xs:sequence>
    <xs:choice>
        <xs:any namespace="my:namespace"/>
        <xs:any namespace="##other" processContents="skip"/>
    </xs:choice>
</xs:sequence>
```

However, of course, this schema is invalid: `my:namespace` is a member of `##other`, so parsing is ambiguous. Attempting to use this schema yields a unique particle attribution violation. Is there any other way to achieve what I've described?

Answer (score 1):

XSD 1.1 allows `xs:any` to have an explicit list of namespaces to be included or excluded.

So many questions follow the pattern "can I do this in XSD" and have the answer "yes, but you need XSD 1.1"...